# Dynamic programming: maximize the number of things to be bought

Tags: dynamic-programming

For example, for a product, we have a list of the number of products you buy and the corresponding price you pay with this number of products:

number = {1, 5, 8, 12}

price = {0.5, 2, 3, 3.6} (i.e. you pay 0.5 for 1 product, 2 for 5 products and so on)

Now I need to use a fixed number of dollars to buy as many number of products as possible. How do I do this using dynamic programming?

I understand how I minimize the cost if I have a fixed number of products I want to buy. But for a fixed amount of money, I get confused, since the price is of type double, I cannot do this with indexing the an array with the prices.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34235876/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.